# C# get generic parameter name using reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

say that I have a C# class like this:

```
class MyClass<Tkey,Tvalue>{}
```

How do I get `"Tkey"` and `"Tvalue"` from given Type instance?
I need the parameter name, not Type.

**EDIT**
My class is of unknown type, so it can be something like

```
class MyClass2<Ttype>{}
```

as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to use the method `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` on the Type to get another Type that represents the generic template. Then you can use `GetGenericArguments()` on that to receive the definition of the original placeholders including their names.

For example:

```
    class MyClass<Tkey, Tvalue> { };


    private IEnumerable<string> GetTypeParameterNames(Type fType)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        if(fType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var lGenericTypeDefinition = fType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            foreach(var lGenericArgument in lGenericTypeDefinition.GetGenericArguments())
            {
                result.Add(lGenericArgument.Name);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void AnalyseObject(object Object)
    {
        if (Object != null)
        {
            var lTypeParameterNames = GetTypeParameterNames(Object.GetType());
            foreach (var name in lTypeParameterNames)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(name + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var object1 = new MyClass<string, string>();
        AnalyseObject(object1);

        var object2 = new List<string>();
        AnalyseObject(object2);

        AnalyseObject("SomeString");
    }
```

Comment: You should probably add a simpler example, without all the unnecessary overhead (you can copy mine, then I'll delete my answer) ;)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i needed

Comment: I simplified it a little but using LINQ: `List<string> genericArguments = T.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                    .GetGenericArguments().Select(q => q.Name).ToList();`

Comment: GetGenericTypeDefinition() will return null when the type is no generic, so you should consider this

Comment: Thanks, I presume that there is a condition for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the Types. From them you can select the name:

```
IEnumerable<string> genericParameterNames = instance.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Select(t => t.Name);
```

**Edit**:

To get the *names* of the generic arguments, you should have a look at [NineBerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35100164/3107430). A simplified version of it is this:

```
IEnumerable<string> genericParameterNames = instance.GetType()
    .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
    .GetGenericArguments()
    .Select(t => t.Name)
```

Comment: This would return the names of the actual types used, not the name of the template arguments

Comment: Yes of course but that gives me the Type name e.g. "Int32". I need to get "Tkey"

Comment: @czubehead oh, I thought these were just placeholder for the actual names. Have you tried Christos answer?

Comment: @czubehead have a look at NineBerry's answer, he explains it very well how to get to those names. I made an edit to my answer to show how to get to those names without the overhead.

Comment: This short form using Linq will throw an exception when the type is no Generic, because GetGenericTypeDefinition() will return null